# Prove uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{nx+1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering if my method for the following proof is correct:

(a) For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set  $f_n:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, 
$f_n(x):=\displaystyle \frac{nx}{nx+1}$. 
Prove that
the sequence 
$\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
is uniformly convergent.
(b) Is the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$,$f_n(x):=\displaystyle \frac{nx}{nx+1}$ 
uniformly convergent? You should prove your claim.

a) want to show $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N \geq 1} \forall_{n \geq N}
\forall_{x \in [1, \infty]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \;
|\frac{nx}{nx + 1} - 1| = |\frac{nx - nx - 1}{nx + 1}| = |\frac{-1}{nx + 1}| = |\frac{1}{nx + 1}| < |\frac{1}{n}|$ 
so take $n = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to satisfy the condition. It follows that ${f_n}$ converges to  $f(x) = 1$ uniformly.

b) $f_n:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, 
$f_n(x):=\displaystyle \frac{nx}{nx+1}$  is not uniformly convergent.
Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. We can pick $x = \frac{1}{n}$ and we have $|\frac{n(\frac{1}{n})}{n(\frac{1}{n}) + 1} - 1|  = |\frac{1}{1 + 1} - 1| = |\frac{1}{2} - 1| = \frac{1}{2} \geq \epsilon$

Comment: Your answer is good.

Comment: Minor point: Choose $N=\lceil \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil$. This way $N$ is actually an integer.